# How can I programmatically generate record definitions?

Tags: clojure, metaprogramming

In my answer to [a Code Review.SE question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87325/52814), I suggested that the OP might consider using records to represent chess pieces. Since the piece records would all be the same, except for the name, I figured I could generate them programmatically, like this:

```
(map #(defrecord % [color]) 
      ["Rook" "Pawn" "Queen" "King" "Knight" "Bishop"])
```

That sort of worked, but my record names weren't the piece names; they were random gensyms: instead of `user.Rook` I got `user.p1__910`. If I did `(p1__910. :black)`, it did work and create a record, but you can probably see why I wasn't satisfied with that.

I also tried the following two variations:

```
(map #(defrecord % [color]) 
      ['Rook 'Pawn 'Queen 'King 'Knight 'Bishop])
  ;; Same result as above.
(map #(defrecord (symbol %) [color])
           ["Rook" "Knight" "Pawn" "Queen" "King" "Bishop"])
  ;; CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList 
  ;; cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:7)
```

What's wrong with my approach? How can I generate a bunch of identical records from a list of names? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic case of macro-contagion.

```
user> defrecord
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/defrecord, compiling:(/tmp/form-init802461651064926183.clj:1:5990)
```

You where very close with the `(symbol %)` idea you just needed to make it so the defrecord expressions generated are evaluated after you provide the values.

```
user> (defmacro make-pieces [piece-names]
        `(do ~@(map #(list 'defrecord (symbol %) '[color]) 
                    piece-names)))
#'user/make-pieces

user> (macroexpand-1 '(make-pieces ["Rook" "Pawn" "Queen" "King" "Knight" "Bishop"]))
(do (defrecord Rook [color]) 
    (defrecord Pawn [color]) 
    (defrecord Queen [color]) 
    (defrecord King [color]) 
    (defrecord Knight [color]) 
    (defrecord Bishop [color]))

user> (make-pieces ["Rook" "Pawn" "Queen" "King" "Knight" "Bishop"])
user.Bishop
```

Comment: My ineptitude with macros bites me again. Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 5):

If all the records are the same, why give them different names? I'd suggest:

```
(defrecord Chess-Piece [name color])
```

What's wrong with your approach is that `defrecord` is a macro, so the "name" argument is interpreted as a symbol and so determines the name for the record *before compiling*. The mapping only occurs during runtime, *after compilation*.

The `%` in your anonymous function is rewritten as a gensym (`p1__910`), which in turn is interpreted as the symbol naming your new record.

What you want to do would have to be done with a macro -- you must simply ensure that by the time `(defrecord some-symbol [color])` is evaluated (again, this is pre-runtime), `some-symbol` is what you want it to be. Maybe something along the lines of:

```
(defmacro defpieces [names]
  (let [defs (map #(list 'defrecord (symbol %) '[color])
                  names)]
    `(do ~@defs)))
```

---

**How your code is being rewritten:**

```
(map #(defrecord % [color]) 
  ["Rook" "Pawn" "Queen" "King" "Knight" "Bishop"])
```

With reader macros, this turns into (roughly):

```
(map (fn* [p1__910#] (defrecord p1__910# [color])
  ["Rook" "Pawn" "Queen" "King" "Knight" "Bishop"])
```

`defrecord` is itself a macro, so (again, before runtime) this is transformed into a giant block of code that contains:

```
(deftype* p1__910# user.p1__910# .....
```

To see the whole block, use the very useful [macroexpand](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand):

```
(macroexpand '(defrecord p1__910# [color]))
```

Comment: If you have just a single Chess-Piece record, you could could use the Entity Component paradigm to implement moves; each piece would be an entity, and each way of moving would be a component.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. It felt cleaner to me to use separate records to allow separate implementations of a protocol for things like limiting the number of spaces the king can move. But I'm very ignorant of game programming; if you have another approach, I bet the OP of [the Code Review question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87325/52814) that inspired me to ask this would like to hear about it.